# Faster every Frame/Second UnrealEngine C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

MyPawn.cpp

```
// Called every frame
void AMyPawn::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    

    // Handle growing and shrinking based on our "Grow" action
    {
        float CurrentScale = OurVisibleComponent->GetComponentScale().X;
        if (bGrowing)
        {
            // Grow to double size over the course of one second
            CurrentScale = CurrentScale + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Shrink half as fast as we grow
            CurrentScale -= (DeltaTime * 0.5f);
        }
        // Make sure we never drop below our starting size, or increase past double size.
        CurrentScale = FMath::Clamp(CurrentScale, 1.0f, 2.0f);
        OurVisibleComponent->SetWorldScale3D(FVector(CurrentScale));
    }

    // Handle movement based on our "MoveX" and "MoveY" axes
    {
        if (!CurrentVelocity.IsZero())
        {
            FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation() + (CurrentVelocity * DeltaTime);
            SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

MyPawn.h

```
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "MyPawn.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT_API AMyPawn : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()


public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    AMyPawn();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    USceneComponent* OurVisibleComponent;

    //Input functions
    void Move_XAxis(float AxisValue);
    void Move_YAxis(float AxisValue);
    void StartGrowing();
    void StopGrowing();

    //Input variables
    FVector CurrentVelocity;
    bool bGrowing;
};
```

I want to add a statement that make my Spawn move faster every Frame or Second while one of the key input pressed   (Forward,Backward,Left or Right),
I've tried to add

CurrentVelocity.X += CurrentVelocity.X

or

CurrentVelocity.X += 1

in the AMyPawn::Tick, and tried some more combination with no success, hope u can help me solve this .

Comment: Why not store the time when the key was first held, calculate the elapsed time between then and the current time, and use that as a multiplier for the base velocity? You may want to cap the multiplier so that things don't get out of hand.

Comment: I just started out with the Engine and CPP, Can't understand from what you are saying what practically i should do.

Comment: It's nothing to do with C++ or any engine. It's basic vector math/physics. If you want an acceleration over time, then you multiply that by the change in time and add to your velocity. `V = V0 + A * dt`